# Tableau dashboard for mobile/tablets

Tags: android, ios, mobile, responsive-design, tableau-api

I am new to Tableau and trying to understand how convenient it is to prepare a dashboard which can be accessed through web browsers, tablets and mobile phones.

I have few questions which are:

1. Does tableau already provides a responsive dashboard which adjusts itself to the device
   width?
2. Can we customize the look and feel of the charts/dashboard to suit our requirements for 
   browsers and tablets?
3. Is there a demo available where I can have a look how a tableau dashboard looks like on 
   various screen widths?
4. Which mobile platforms does tableau supports (Android, iOS, Win)

Comment: Not sure if there is a way to customize to each size of screen yourself, but if you choose automatic fit, Tableau usually does a good job fitting everything

Answer (score 1):

In Tableau, you don’t have to do anything special to make a dashboard mobile. Simply publish to Tableau Server like you always have, and Tableau will detect if you’re using the Mobile app.
Dashboard you can select options iPad, desktop or automatic even you can specify custom size of your dashboard.
you go to Tableau Server from your mobile browser, without the app at all.
no special authoring or design changes are required to make views and dashboards automatically work on your tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Tableau does not provide Responsive UI. It does provide automatic resizing. There is a [enhancement](http://community.tableausoftware.com/ideas/2836) filed in Tableau forum to support responsive UI.

Answer (score 0):

The trick with Tableau dashboards on mobile is to design the dashboard to fit the screen size of the smallest device you want it to work on. Dashbaords can be set to automatically resize, but the results are acceptable but not perfect as some dashboard elements will often end up truncated on smaller screens.

The best way to experiment with this is to test the dashboard you are building using different screen sizes and see how they work (you can set the minimal size you want as the base by choosing an option to make the designed size the minimal size; dashboards will then expand if the actual size is larger). Some device screens are selectable automatically for convenience (iPad, for example) ad it is worth testing these out when designing a dashboard. ([here](http://public.tableausoftware.com/views/KingJamesBiblev2_4/treemap?%3aembed=y&%3adisplay_count=no) is a Tableau Public one I built earlier sized exactly for an iPad).

The interaction UI elements adjust automatically to the device browser standard which saves a lot of effort.

Tableau will support any device with a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Along with automatic settings, you also need to make the container FIT-> 'Entire View'

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpaec.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Responsive Tableau Dashboard in Mobile and Tablet.
   Example Code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
   function growIframe() {  
   document.getElementById('embededView').height = 1000;
   }
</script>
</head>

 <body onclick="growIframe()">

 <iframe id="embededView" src="http://localhost/workbook/view" width ="1322"
 height="900 "></iframe>

 </body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the dashboard itself will automatically resize, but the responsiveness is limited to the dashboard design. What you can do, however, to is design multiple dashboards, one for each screen size you wish to accommodate, and embed them within a css framework on a custom page.

See how [this person](https://public.tableau.com/s/blog/2014/11/making-responsive-tableau-dashboards) does it.

Each dashboard will ultimately contain identical data/visuals, but arranged in different ways to better suit differently sized screens.

If a certain visual will not fit on a mobile screen, you will have to think of a creative way to display this data differently on mobile, or just eliminate it from the mobile view.